# Crop a hotel object from an image file using java

Tags: java, image-processing, object-detection

There are several images with aspect ratio with 5 and height 4. Those images contains hotel images with roads and other environment objects. I want to crop this images to get the hotel images without other environment objects. That mean analyze the given image file and detect the hotel object and crop it and save as image file. Can anyone guide me to do this using java please?

Comment: How would you do this using the language of your choice? What research or coding did you do already?

Comment: Sorry for the late. Did some analysis on java image processing and unable to find object identification. other language also ok like python.